# Highcharts : pattern-fill doesn't work with export server

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to export a chart using the module pattern-fill and it doesn't work with the export server

Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vs9hjne5/4/

I am using the same configuration in the page https://export.highcharts.com/

[image]

Here is the property for the export.highcharts service :

```
{
 "series":[
  {
    "color":{
      "pattern":{
        "path":{
          "strokeWidth":1,
          "d":"M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11"
        },
        "backgroundColor":"#5B799E",
        "color":"#F6A800",
        "width":10,
        "opacity":1,
        "height":10
      }
    },
    "data":[[1,10]],
    "type":"column"
  }
 ]
}
```

if I change the color property from

```
"color":{
      "pattern":{
        "path":{
          "strokeWidth":1,
          "d":"M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11"
        },
        "backgroundColor":"#5B799E",
        "color":"#F6A800",
        "width":10,
        "opacity":1,
        "height":10
      }
    }
```

to

```
"color":"red"
```

it works

[image]

How can I export a chart with the module pattern-fill with the export server ?

edit : I found a solution, I had to modify the build.js file to add "{{version}}/modules/pattern-fill.js" in the variable **cdnScriptsCommon** in the **node_modules/highcharts-export-server directory**, execute **node build.js** to re-generate the service and restart the service

Comment: Are you also testing export in a local environment?

Comment: yes and it doesn't work either

Comment: To use a pattern you need to load [pattern-fill.js](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.js) is loading properly?

Comment: I can export a Heatmap without explicit load of the heatmap.js file why not with pattern ?

Comment: It's look like this problem occurs because export server using PhantomJS, [topic1](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/179).  Describe when exporting using Puppeteer based server it works properly, [topic2](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/143#issuecomment-1138893576).

Comment: I found a solution, I had to modify the build.js file to add "{{version}}/modules/pattern-fill.js" in the node_modules/highcharts-export-server directory, execute node build.js to re-generate the service and restart the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I had to modify the build.js file to add "{{version}}/modules/pattern-fill.js" in the node_modules/highcharts-export-server directory, execute node build.js to re-generate the service and restart the service